# calling startActivity() inside of a instance method - causing a NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-internet

Heya - I'm trying to call startActivity() from a class that extends AsyncTask in the onPostExecute().

Here's the flow:

Class that extends AsyncTask:

```
protected void onPostExecute() {
    Login login = new Login();
    login.pushCreateNewOrChooseExistingFormActivity();
}
```

Class that extends Activity:

```
public void pushCreateNewOrChooseExistingFormActivity() {
    // start the CreateNewOrChooseExistingForm Activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    **ERROR_HERE*** intent.setClassName(this, CreateNewOrChooseExistingForm.class.getName());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And I get this error… every time:

```
03-17 16:04:29.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 16:04:29.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1503): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 16:04:29.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1503): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
03-17 16:04:29.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1503): at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:62)
03-17 16:04:29.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1503): at android.content.Intent.setClassName(Intent.java:4850)
03-17 16:04:29.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1503): at com.att.AppName.Login.pushCreateNewOrChooseExistingFormActivity(Login.java:47)
```

For iOS developers - I'm just trying to push a new view controller on to a navigational controller's stack a la `pushViewController:animated:`.  Which apparently - is hard to do on this platform.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE - FIXED:

per @Falmarri advice, i managed to resolve this issue.

first of all, i'm no longer calling `Login login = new Login();` to create a new login object. bad. bad. bad. no cookie.

instead, when preparing to call `.execute()`, this tutorial (appfulcrum.com/?p=126) suggests passing the applicationContext to the class the executes the AsyncTask, for my purposes, as shown below:

```
    CallWebServiceTask task = new CallWebServiceTask();
    // pass the login object to the task
    task.applicationContext = login;
    // execute the task in the background, passing the required params
    task.execute(login);
```

now, in `onPostExecute()`, i can get to my Login objects methods like so:

```
        ((Login) applicationContext).pushCreateNewOrChooseExistingFormActivity();
        ((Login) applicationContext).showLoginFailedAlert(result.get("httpResponseCode").toString());
        ...
```

hope this helps someone else out there! especially iOS developers transistioning over to Android...

Comment: Did you declare your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Android != iPhone  Make sure you have read and understood the Android fundamentals where they explain about the main parts of Android (i.e. Activities).  There is no concept of a navigational controller, or a view controller.  That doesn't mean what you are trying to do is hard, its just different from the iPhone way.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Comment: @Malcolm, yes:
...
<activity android:label="@string/createneworchooseexistingform_view_title" android:name=".CreateNewOrChooseExistingForm"></activity>
...

@Mayra, will do - back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Login` is a class that extends `Activity`, you should never, ever, ever, be creating a new `Login` object yourself such as

```
Login login = new Login();
```

This is very, very wrong and you should go back and go through some of the Android tutorials.

Comment: I was following this tutorial (minus my great idea to creating a new Login object - that's just my objective-c patterns getting in the way). 

http://appfulcrum.com/?p=126

would you mind explaining what line 13 in the btnCallWebService.setOnClickListener() is doing? i'd ask on that post, but the comments are closed.

thanks in advance!

Comment: `Start.this` is a reference to the current Start activity. Since Activity extends Context, what that line is doing is saving a reference to the activity's context which is required for most things in android.